# Revisiting Bash vs Source difference

Tags: bash, scripts, source

I want to ask a question about bash and source.

I acknowledge they are both used with .sh extension files such as

```
bash setup.sh
source setup.sh
```

However, I wanted to know a difference between those two if one could explain.

There is a post [Using source vs bash commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/306523/using-source-vs-bash-commands), which attempted to explain, but I could not clarify if the responder tried to say "source" ignores past definition and sets environment variables in current shell or bash ignores past definition and sets environment variables in current shell.

If one could provide a better description of difference between source and bash, that would be great as well.

Thank you!

Comment: Unix/linux file extensions are not required at all. They generally just act as hints to your editor or default appliation launcher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link you provided does not mention "past definition", probably because this does not matter. `source` operates in the current shell and can affect variables in the current shell. `bash` invokes a new shell and that shell cannot affect the environment of its parent. Also, the `.sh` extension is completely optional and is specifically not used in shell initialization files.

Comment: Technically "specifically not used in shell initialization files" is not true: bash login shells source `/etc/profile` and that file does `for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh`

Answer (score 3):

What happens when you run `bash foo.sh` ?
A fresh bash process starts and reads and executes the commands that are in `foo.sh`. When it's done executing the commands, this new process exits and you get your prompt back, echoed by your current shell.

What happens when you run `source foo.sh` (or `. foo.sh`) ?
You basically tell your current shell "instead of reading commands from the keyboard, read commands from this file, when you're done, come back to the keyboard"

When does it matter ?
When there are commands that change the state of the shell; for example `cd`, `exit`, `VAR=value`, `alias` and a few other.

Suppose `foo.sh` contains this :

```
mkdir /tmp/bar
```

It does not matter if you run it with `source` or `bash`.
Now, suppose the content of the script changes variables, then it matters. When you run `bash foo.sh`, a new bash is created, it runs the commands and exits; no change in your shell. If, on the other side,  you `source foo.sh`, **your current shell variables** are changed.

Let's take an example. Suppose there is this in file `foo.sh`:

```
echo "Currently executing commands from foo.sh"
echo "changing variable foo."
foo=$RANDOM
echo "In shell with PID $$, the value of foo is now >>$foo<<"
echo "End of foo.sh"; echo
```

What happens if you run `bash foo.sh` and then `echo $foo` ?
What happens if you run `source foo.sh` and then `echo $foo` ?

Try multiple times. You'll notice that if you run `bash foo.sh`, the foo variable is not set in your shell. if you run `source foo.sh`, the foo variable is set (and changed) each time.